# <option ng-repeat value={{object}}> How can i force angular to push the object into the model?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an angular 1.2.x project in which I need to use  in order to be able to set a title and disable different options.
Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/SUXpFOXvSUFVmi1itkf1?p=preview

```
 <select ng-change="onConceptNameSelect()"
        ng-model="result">
        <option value="">Select value
        </option>
        <option ng-repeat="value in values" 
                value={{value}}
                title="{{value.title}}"
                ng-disabled="value.isDisabled">{{value.name}}
        </option>
</select>
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I do a selection, the ng-model will be initialized with the stringified object instead of being initialized with the object itself.

How can i force angular to push the object into the model?

Thanks

Comment: Because I cannot change it to 2 or any other newer version. It's a big old projects with too many dependencies

Comment: @KevinSimple what is the relevance? There are thousands of existing projects and even many new ones won't use something that isn't production ready

Comment: sure, you can, angular 2 have compatible mode for running both angular 1 and 2 code together.

Comment: Use `ng-options` and then you can bind object to model

Comment: Well if i could have i would have done it already. Changing the angular version is not an option at this moment.

Comment: @charlietfl in my angular version ng-options doesn't support disable and title. So i'm kind of stuck with the ng-repeat

Comment: @gelugara, go with charlie's solution, mate

Comment: @charlietfl, see the issue with old tech?

Comment: can you filter them out instead of using disable? Other alternative is bind to something else and use `ng-change` to update model

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the String value to object if you really need the object

Have a look at this [updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NcLCRK?p=preview)

```js
$scope.isObject = function() {
    return $scope.resultObject instanceof Object;
};
  
$scope.onConceptNameSelect = function () {
    $scope.resultObject = $scope.$eval($scope.result);
};
```